# RubyMine does not highlight ruby code in js.coffee files

Tags: coffeescript, highlight, rubymine

RubyMine does not highlight ruby code inside js.coffee files despite the plugin is ON (Plugins sections in Settings) and coffeescript itself is highlighted. I can not move to `/works/modal` pressing F4 or even see it highlighted properly.

[image]